# Aggregate the rows of python Spark DataFrame by 10 min intervals

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Can I achieve this in pySpark python? By optimizing a little or not. please I am blocked**

**Initial csv**

| Date | Time | idSensor1 | valueSensor1 | idSensor2 | valueSensor2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210113 | 10:01:01.000000 | 171 | 5 | 173 | 8 |
| 20210113 | 10:05:05.111111 | 171 | 6 | 172 | 8 |
| 20210113 | 10:08:08.222222 | 171 | 4 | 172 | 8 |
| 20210113 | 10:10:10.333333 | 171 | 6 | 172 | 8 |
| 20210113 | 10:15:15.444444 | 171 | 8 | 172 | 10 |
| 20210113 | 10:18:18.555555 | 171 | 9 | 172 | 10 |

**we aggregate the values ​​of the last 10 minutes   of the column valueSensor1 and valueSensor2 to separate**

| Date | Time | idSensor1 | valueSensor1 | idSensor2 | valueSensor2 | intervalsValuesSensor1 | intervalsValuesSensor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210113 | 10:01:01.000000 | 171 | 5 | 173 | 8 | [] | [] |
| 20210113 | 10:05:05.111111 | 171 | 6 | 172 | 8 | [5] | [8] |
| 20210113 | 10:08:08.222222 | 171 | 4 | 172 | 8 | [5,6] | [8,8] |
| 20210113 | 10:10:10.333333 | 171 | 6 | 172 | 8 | [5,6,4] | [8,8,8] |
| 20210113 | 10:15:15.444444 | 171 | 8 | 172 | 10 | [6,4,6] | [8,8,8] |
| 20210113 | 10:18:18.555555 | 171 | 9 | 172 | 10 | [4,6,8] | [8,8,10] |

**we aggregate the values ​​of the last 10 minutes  SUM of the column valueSensor1 and valueSensor2
**

| Date | Time | idSensor1 | valueSensor1 | idSensor2 | valueSensor2 | intervalsSumAll |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210113 | 10:01:01.000000 | 171 | 5 | 173 | 8 | [] |
| 20210113 | 10:05:05.111111 | 171 | 6 | 172 | 8 | [13] |
| 20210113 | 10:08:08.222222 | 171 | 4 | 172 | 8 | [13,14] |
| 20210113 | 10:10:10.333333 | 171 | 6 | 172 | 8 | [13,14,12] |
| 20210113 | 10:15:15.444444 | 171 | 8 | 172 | 10 | [14,12,14] |
| 20210113 | 10:18:18.555555 | 171 | 9 | 172 | 10 | [12,14,18] |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collect_list` over a window ordered by the unix timestamp, ranging between 600 seconds (10 minutes) before the current row to 1 second before the current row:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'intervalsValuesSensor1', 
    F.collect_list('valueSensor1').over(
        Window.partitionBy('idSensor1')
              .orderBy(F.unix_timestamp(F.concat('Date', 'Time'), 'yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'))
              .rangeBetween(-600, -1)
    )
)

df2.show()
+--------+---------------+---------+------------+---------+------------+----------------------+
|    Date|           Time|idSensor1|valueSensor1|idSensor2|valueSensor2|intervalsValuesSensor1|
+--------+---------------+---------+------------+---------+------------+----------------------+
|20210113|10:01:01.000000|      171|           5|      173|           8|                    []|
|20210113|10:05:05.111111|      171|           6|      172|           8|                   [5]|
|20210113|10:08:08.222222|      171|           4|      172|           8|                [5, 6]|
|20210113|10:10:10.333333|      171|           6|      172|           8|             [5, 6, 4]|
|20210113|10:15:15.444444|      171|           8|      172|          10|                [4, 6]|
|20210113|10:18:18.555555|      171|           9|      172|          10|                [6, 8]|
+--------+---------------+---------+------------+---------+------------+----------------------+
```

And similarly you can do this for `Sensor2`. For the sum, you can just do `F.collect_list(F.col('valueSensor1') + F.col('valueSensor2'))`